# Ternary/null coalescing operator and assignment expression on the right-hand side?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

While experimenting with ternary and null coalesce operators in C# I discovered that it is possible to use assignments on the right-hand side of expressions, for example this is a valid C# code:

```
int? a = null;
int? b = null;
int? c = a ?? (b = 12);
int? d = a == 12 ? a : (b = 15);
```

Strangely enough, not only the assignment on the right-hand side of the expression is evaluated to its own right-hand side (meaning that the third line here is evaluated to `12` and not to something like `b = 12 => void`), but this assignment also effectively works, so that two variables are assigned in one statement. One can also use any computable expression on the right-hand side of this assignment, with any available variable.

This behaviour seems to me to be very strange. I remember having troubles with `if (a = 2)`  instead of `if (a == 2)`  comparison in C++, which is always evaluated to `true` and this is a common mistake after switching from Basic/Haskell to C++.

Is it a documented feature? Is there any name for it?

Comment: beware of the brackets ... if(2 == (a =2 )) ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens as consequence of the [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) also returning the value:

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and returns the value as its result.

The expression `b = 12` not only assigns 12 to `b`, but also returns this value.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple assignment works in C#:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
a = b = c = 5;
//all variables = 5;

if(6 == (c = 6)){
   //this will be true;
}
```

If you put a variable on the right side of an equation, even if it has just been assigned a value itself on the same line, it returns its value/reference.