# C# List<T>.Add not adding properly

Tags: c#

Using `.Add` to add an instance of a class to a generic list is not working.

To illustrate the problem, here are two simple example classes:

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    private List<Note> _Notes;
    public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            return _Notes ?? new List<Note>();
        }
        set
        {
            _Notes = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Note
{
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

You may notice the coding in `get` on the `WorkOrder.Notes` property. I put this in so the property wouldn't be initialized with a null value (ref an answer to another question I posted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688359/2658159)).

To utilize these classes:

```
public void Test()
{
    WorkOrder tempWorkOrder = new WorkOrder();
    Note tempNote = new Note()
    {
        User = "Aaron",
        Time = DateTime.Now,
        NoteText = "Work Order pulled from CSV Excel report."
    };
    tempWorkOrder.Notes.Add(tempNote);
}
```

I would expect the last line in `Test()` to add `tempNote` to the list of `Note` in `tempWorkOrder`. However, `tempWorkOrder.Notes` is null after this line completes. No errors or exceptions are thrown.

I'm using VS2013 Express.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i wouldn't lazy create the instance of the list - you could cause some unexpected behavior.

Comment: return _Notes ?? new List<Note>();
Does the following, if _Notes is not null, returns it, if it is NULL a new list is created and returned, but never assigned to _Notes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
private List<Note> _Notes;
public List<Note> Notes
{
    get
    {
        return _Notes ?? new List<Note>();
    }
    set
    {
        _Notes = value;
    }
}
```

The `get` is wrong. It should be:

```
    get
    {
        if (_Notes == null) {
            _Notes = new List<Note>();
        }
        return _Notes;
    }
```

because otherwise you don't save the `new List<Note>()` you created and every time you use the `get` you recreate it (the `get` returns a `new List<Note>()` but doesn't modify `_Notes`, so every `get` checks `_Notes`, see it's `null` and return a `new List<Note>()`)

Note that if you hate the world (and your fellow programmers) you can compact the `get` to:

```
return _Notes ?? (_Notes = new List<Note>());
```

(see [Ternary/null coalescing operator and assignment expression on the right-hand side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385931/ternary-null-coalescing-operator-and-assignment-expression-on-the-right-hand-sid)) I don't hate enough the world (and my fellow programmers) to do it :-)

Comment: That's it. Looks like all answers so far are correct, but this one answers most completely. Thanks all!

Comment: I don't get the "hate" for `return _Notes ?? (_Notes = new List<Note>());`. I think it's very clear and in fact i like it more than the single-line `if`. The linked thread shows some potential for misuse, but you can misuse almost everything.

Comment: @Corak The single line if was because I was writing directly in the editor of SO that doesn't auto-indent :-) I always use `if {}`. The "hate" of `=` inside another expression is probably connected to the "one line, one effect" way of writing code and/or to the tons of bugs caused by the `=` assignment vs `==` equality operator in C/C++

Comment: @xanatos - thanks, I see. Well, with "one line, one effect", one won't get far with Linq method chaining. ^_^;

Comment: @Corak No, because Linq methods are side-effect free (each member of the chain produces something new), so they are ok.

Comment: @Corak See for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx on LINQ + side effects

Answer (score 2):

You have not created the list yet there. You need to add a constructor to the `WorkOrder` as you cannot add to a collection that does not exist. This way, whenever you create a Work Order, you will have an empty list in the `_Notes' field.

It would look something like this:

```
WorkOrder(){
    _Notes = new List<Note>();
}
```

Comment: In EF (Which is what the OP is doing in the other question) this is the normal way to initialize the ICollections.

Comment: Just wanted to point out: this question is for a class that is not tied in with EF - although yes it could easily be made to apply in a Code First situation.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign `_Notes`

Do this instead

```
    private List<Note> _Notes;
    public List<Note> Notes
    {
        get
        {
            if(_Notes == null)
                 _Notes = new List<Note>();
            return _Notes;
        }
        set
        {
            _Notes = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `_Notes`.

So while you get a `List<Note>` back when `_Notes` is null, it is not assigning the object to `_Notes`. Each time you access the public property, it is returning a different `List<Note>` which is why the `Add()` call appears to not work.

You should rather use:

```
get 
{ 
  if (_Notes == null) 
     _Notes = new List<Note>(); 
  return _Notes; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use the null-coalescing assignment if you are using C# 8, like so:

`get => _Notes ??= new List<Note>();`

With brackets:

`get
{
    return _Notes ??= new List<Note>();
}`

Answer (score 0):

In the getter for `Notes`, you're doing nothing to save a reference to the newly-created list.  Therefore, every time you access that getter, you'll get a fresh, empty list.  So this:

```
tempWorkOrder.Notes.Add(tempNote);
```

...is adding `tempNote` to a `List<Note>` that is immediately thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your get method:

```
    get
    {
        return _Notes ?? new List<Note>();
    }
```

Since you don't assign the reference of the object you're creating to `_Notes`, it keeps being null, and you assigned to a list that isn't referenced anywhere else.

This is what you can do instead:

```
    get
    {
        if (_Notes == null)
            _Notes = new List<Note>();
        return _Notes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    public List<Note> Notes {get;set;}

    public WorkOrder()
    {
        Notes = new List<Note>();
    }
}
```

But in C# 6.0 you should be able to do the following:

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    public List<Note> Notes {get;set;} = new List<Note>();                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, you can create a small extension method which can guard against null or empty list:

```
public static bool NotNullAndEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
  if (source != null && source.Any())
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Also, if you are using database, then its advisable to use `IEnumerable` and do all modifications with `IEnumerable`. Once done, call `.ToList(`) which will result in a single call to the database.